# Budogyuu- what does this term mean?

Tags: terminology

https://8-burger.com/ lists its premium burger as having BudoGyuu 100%-jusshi. I didn't find this term on Linguee and Google translate.

Could anyone  explain this term fully?

Comment: It seems like the explanation you found covers it pretty well... what else did you want to know?

Comment: How about a primary source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[https://prtimes.jp/main/html/rd/p/000000091.000027084.html#:~:text=%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E7%94%A3%E5%9C%B0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C,%E7%94%98%E3%81%84%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8A%E8%82%89%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82](https://prtimes.jp/main/html/rd/p/000000091.000027084.html#:%7E:text=%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E7%94%A3%E5%9C%B0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C,%E7%94%98%E3%81%84%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8A%E8%82%89%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82)

葡萄牛
"Grape cows" are grown on designated farms that meet strict internationally recognized standards in Australia's vast lands and abundant wilderness. Australia is world-famous for producing wine, but as the name suggests, "grape beef" is a branded beef that has been carefully raised for a long time by eating grape lees squeezed at a winery. Beef raised on a special feed is a juicy meat that is soft and tasty, and slightly sweet.